# Get name of a new user on signup and store in database with Cloud Functions

Tags: typescript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-functions

In my client I have a sign up screen, where the user gives a name, an email and a password to sign up.

When this happens, I want to create a user's document within my Firestore database that contains the name and email of this user.

As of now, I managed to get the email of that user but I am unable to save also its name:

```
export const createUserDocument = functions
.region(config.cloud_functions.region)
.auth.user().onCreate((user, context) => {
    const documentRef = firestore.doc(`Users/${user.uid}`);
    return documentRef.set({ email: user?.email}); 
});
```

The cloud function should get called after the following code in the client:

```
  @override
  Future<void> signupWithCredentials(String email, String password) async {
    try {
      await _firebaseAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
        email: email,
        password: password,
      );
    } catch (e) {
      return handleFirestoreError(e);
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

New email/password accounts create with Firebase Authentication do not have a name associated with them.  While you can add the name after creation using `updateProfile()`, that information will not make it into the auth trigger.

If you want to add a name to the document, you will have to do that with another update to the document that was created by the trigger.

Comment: So this means I need a second cloud function that I should use with the `updateProfile()` method? Could you suggest a documentation on how to implement this?

Comment: You can write that document any way you want, and you can do it either on the client or server.  You choose.  Firebase Auth and Firestore have a lot of great documentation to work with.